# Airflow - Dependencies from Database

Tags: python, dynamic, dependencies, airflow, task

I am trying to configurate Airflow dependences from a Dataframe.

I could generate diferents tasks from a pandas Dataframe, but i couldn't with the deoendencies.

The principal idea is give the possibility to inexperienced users, to add tasks with certains dependences.

First i generate from a class object a list of task to create:

```
tasks = ETL_Process(MAIN_MODULE)
```

Now within tasks I have different Dataframes created from the given parameter.

Then, when i have that list, y iterate them for creating the differnts tasks.

```
for index, row in tasks.DF_PROCESS_LIST.iterrows():
    ID_TASK = row["id_process"]
    NAME_TASK = str(row["id_process"])

    ID_TASK = DummyOperator(task_id=NAME_TASK, dag=dag)
```

This works fine, i have my tasks created on airflow. But now, i have the dependencies too. I can't get them to work. I want to iterate the DF and generate a simple airflow dependency with '>>' characters, with no luck.

I want to generate dependences from a dataframe. Any ideas?

The last try was:

```
for index, row in tasks.DF_DEPENDENCES.iterrows():
    print('{} >> {}'.format(row['process_id'],  row['depends_on_id']))
    int(row['process_id']) >> int(row['depends_on_id'])
```

Dont work for me. The print is for test purpose.

Thanks!

I want to generate automatically the Airflow Diagram with dependencies, from a dinamic Dataframe generated into a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `>>` that set dependencies need to be between task objects, I think in your example you are trying to use them on the task name strings.
I suggest you collect the task objects you create in your first loop.

The following DAG uses a Pandas dataframe with 2 columns, one for task IDs `id_process` one for the tasks that each of these depend `depends_on_id` and collects the generated task objects in a third column `task_objects`:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id_process": ["task_0", "task_1", "task_2", "task_3", "task_4"], 
        "depends_on_id": ["", "task_0", "task_1", "task_1", "task_2"]
    }
)

with DAG(
    dag_id="dependencies_from_dataframe",
    start_date=datetime(2022,12,10),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
    tags=["dep", "pandas"]
) as dag:

    task_objects = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        NAME_TASK = str(row["id_process"])

        my_task = EmptyOperator(task_id=NAME_TASK)

        task_objects.append(my_task)

    df["task_objects"] = task_objects

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row["depends_on_id"] == "":
            continue

        obj_depend = df["task_objects"].where(
            df["id_process"] == row["depends_on_id"]
        ).dropna(axis=0).values[0]

        obj_depend >> row["task_objects"]
```

The DAG created by this code:

[image: DAG with simple dependencies]